# problems with styling svg

Tags: html, css, svg

Hello I have problem with styling svg in mozilla. In chrome and opera css like { r: 45 } works fine but in mozilla and IE, EDGE does't

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle id="circle" r="50" cx="50" cy="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: I know the duplicate is about width and height of a rect but the answer applies for the attributes of a circle just as much as the for attributes of a rect.

Comment: can you give me the link of answer

Comment: It's just below the text that says This question already has an answer here: